# What to commit when using Carthage?

Tags: git, carthage

This is my first time using Carthage! I'm using a library called "https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController" and I got it to work on my project. The issue is I want to commit these changes but when I do I got a popup saying that a certain file was bigger then 10MB!

The question again is, What are you suppose to commit and not commit when using Carthage?

Picture of such file:

[image]

On source tree:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/LeoNatan Please check this out!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Carthage/Carthage issue 393](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/393) covers this.

It refers to [`github/gitignore/Swift.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/1a9f616ce525987555d43c72d59eb830d1856bd7/Swift.gitignore#L51-L56) as a possible example:

```
# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.
# Carthage/Checkouts/

Carthage/Build/
```

This leaves `Cartfile`, `Cartfile.private`, and `Cartfile.resolved` to be committed.

But: do refer to the [Carthage Artifacts page](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/83bbffd25172df767cf578ca17b0cfbbbf913d35/Documentation/Artifacts.md):

For the `Checkouts` folders:

> You are not required to commit this folder to your repository, but you may wish to, if you want to guarantee that the built versions of each dependency will always be accessible at a later date.

So in your case, it is simpler to add `Carthage/Checkouts/` to your `.gitignore`.
Then SourceTree won't list all those files as unstaged.

Comment: I just added another picture to my question. I'm sure what to commit here?

Comment: @user7097242 Simply add `Carthage/Checkouts/` to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Like this?:                                                                                                                 # Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.

Carthage/Checkouts
Carthage/Build

Comment: @user7097242 Yes, in your .gitignore file (without any leading '#')

Comment: This seems to work. Can you please explain why that carthage library had so many files such as that and why I should ignore it? I'm use to using cocoa pods and never had to deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: @user7097242 That is what https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/83bbffd25172df767cf578ca17b0cfbbbf913d35/Documentation/Artifacts.md explains.